# const expression needed for static class initialization

Tags: c++

This program may look like foolish program but i want to know the solution for it

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
     static int i;
     static int &j = i;
};

int base::i=9;

int main()
{

    cout<<base::j<<" "<<base::i;

    return 0;
}
```

when i am compiling this program i am getting the error "const expression needed for static class initialization"
can anyone help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Simple: move it out of class as well:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
     static int i;
     static int &j;
};

int base::i=9;
int &base::j=base::i;

int main()
{

    cout<<base::j<<" "<<base::i;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/Krp85q)

Comment: @user2413497 If it works for you, you can accept the answer (green tickmark). That's how SO works.